# Running Bot project outside Bot Framework Composer

Tags: azure, bot-framework-composer

Hello we have a bot service created with Microsoft Bot framework composer, but now we need to run that service outside of composer. Please do you know if is possible extract the project and run in nginx for example?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can run it anywhere where you host usual dotnet core api.

You can publish the bot like an dotnet core api from visual studio or devops pipeline and deploy the code build to iis or server.

NOTE: you can open the same solution you develop in Bot Framework Composer in an Visual Studio like any dotnet core project.

As per comment from @Isaac we can run using following command:

```
dotnet run --MicrosoftAppPassword=XX
```

Comment: I can run the project with "dotnet run" but it becomes unresponsive when testing in the emulator. Are there any additional parameters composer uses to run it?

Comment: Found it! In case anybody has the same problem, if you have configured a MicrosoftAppId you have to pass in the password as a command line argument like "--MicrosoftAppPassword=XX"